# Hide command prompt window in Edge driver browser when running .exe in Windows application using c# language

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Unable to hide command prompt when running edge driver browser in c# windows application.
I have tried this code:

```
IWebDriver dr = new EdgeDriver(EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(".", Dir + "\\" + "msedgedriver.exe"));
dr.HideCommandPromptWindow= "true";
```

I don't know what method will have the definition for hidecommandPromptWindow. I followed this code from "Hide command prompt in chromedriver browser". But I need the exact code for edge browser.